# Setting up an oracle database with Play 2.0.4

Tags: java, oracle, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database via Play Framework 2.0.4.

I keep getting a configuration error "Driver not found: [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]".

Software involved

Windows 7 64bit / 
IntelliJ 12.0.4 /
Play 2.0.4 /
Java JDK 1.7 64bit

I downloaded the ojdbc6-11.jar file from oracle and added it to the libraries in IntelliJ
 via file -> project structure -> libraries. I have also added the file to classpath and path but it does not seem to work.

The related information in application.conf is as follows

```
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserverinformation:port/servicename"

db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

db.default.user=user

db.default.password=pass
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add it to your project's lib folder as follow:
yourProject/lib/ojdbc6-11.jar

That is the directory where Play looks for external library. Alternatively, you may use maven to install libraries (given that they are available there), see the Build.scala file in yourProject/project

See: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/SBTDependencies

Comment: Cyril D, I create a folder called lib inside my project and put the jdbc driver inside it and it seems to have worked. Thanks and godspeed.